# Vertical and Oblique asymptotes

Tags: calculus

Why can't a function have an oblique and horizontal asymptote?

I think its because when graphed the function would no longer pass the vertical line test. Am I right on this? Or could someone expand on this idea a bit more?

Comment: The premise of the question is wrong. Consider a function $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $\lvert x \rvert$ for $x<0$ and $0$ for $x \geq 0$.

Comment: A visualization to @Jubobs' comment: [W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot[Piecewise[{{|x|%2B2%2Cx%3E%3D0}%2C{2%2Cx%3C0}}]%2C+{x%2C+-5%2C+5}])

Comment: @OP: Perhaps you're thinking of a *rational function*?

Comment: Good thought @anorton.  If this is a school problem and they are working on asymptotes, very likely there is an (implicit) restriction to rational functions.

Answer (score 1):

A function **can** have an oblique and a horizontal asymptote, for example
$$f(x)=\frac{(1+x)e^x}{1+e^x}\ .$$
If $x\to\infty$ we have
$$f(x)=\frac{1+x}{1+e^{-x}}$$
which is asymptotic to $1+x$, while if $x\to-\infty$ then $f(x)\to0$.